# Assign sub-nested JSON string to HTML Input Type radio's value

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am working on Angular application and I need to read nested array value 'subOption.name' for input type radio's value but I am getting error as, I am not sure if error is metaData structure or in input type?

### Metadata

```
options: [
              {subQuestionTitle: 'Consult with SIG SMEs', subOption:[
                {name:'consult-sig-sme', key: '1',  value: 'impact'},
                {name:'consult-sig-sme', key: '2',  value: 'no-impact'},
                {name:'consult-sig-sme', key: '3',   value: 'not-reviewed'}
              ]},
              {subQuestionTitle: 'Plan Profile', subOption:[
                {name:'plan-profile', key: '1',  value: 'impact'},
                {name:'plan-profile', key: '2',  value: 'no-impact'},
                {name:'plan-profile', key: '3',   value: 'not-reviewed'}
              ]},
              {subQuestionTitle: 'Offshore or US?', subOption:[
                {name:'offshore', key: '1',  value: 'impact'},
                {name:'offshore', key: '2',  value: 'no-impact'},
                {name:'offshore', key: '3',   value: 'not-reviewed'}
              ]},
              {subQuestionTitle: 'Impacts & Awareness for IPMs & DCCs?', subOption:[
                {name:'impacts-and-awareness', key: '1',  value: 'impact'},
                {name:'impacts-and-awareness', key: '2',  value: 'no-impact'},
                {name:'impacts-and-awareness', key: '3',   value: 'not-reviewed'}
              ]}
    ],
```

### Template

```
<div class="grid-row" *ngFor="let opt of question.options">
            <input type="radio" value="impact" [name]="opt.subOption.name"> 
            <input type="radio" value="no-impact" [name]="opt.subOption.name"> 
            <input type="radio" value="not-reviewed" [name]="opt.subOption.name"> 
</div>
```

### Error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subOption' of undefined
```

if I update code as

```
<input type="radio" value="impact" [name]="opt.subOption">

I can see following implementation in source F12

<input _ngcontent-c0="" type="radio" value="impact" name="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]">
```

Comment: Are you looping somewhere in your template through the `options` array? How are you getting `opt` ?

Comment: I am looping in div, *ngFor="let opt of question.options" also update my question under template heading

Comment: Are you getting the metadata asynchronously?

Comment: no its is hard-coded at the movement. beside I can read subQuestionTitle which is first value in array, so I believe is I am not reading in right way sub-nested array in <input>

Comment: I update my question with other details at bottom

Comment: There is no name for subOption, because it is an array. Try name="{{opt.subOption[0].name}}"

Comment: So do you want a radio input for each of the objects inside each of the `subOptions` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
<div class="grid-row" *ngFor="let opt of options">
  {{opt.subQuestionTitle}} <br/>
  <span *ngFor="let suboption of opt.subOption">
    <input type="radio"[value]="suboption.value" [name]="suboption.name"/>
    {{suboption.value}}
  </span>
</div>
```

Best way of doing this would be to create more smaller components e.g. the entire content inside the `<span>...</span>` can be `SubOptionsComponent` and each `input radio` and the value then can be a `SubOptionComponent`